# Simple Closed Geodesics in Mapping Torus Via Pseudo Anasove Homeomorphism?

Tags: dynamical-systems, geometric-topology, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

Recently I have been reading the book A Primer on Mapping Class Groups by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit. Let $S_g=$ Closed surface of genus $g$, and $Mod(S_g)$ denoted the corresponding mapping class group.

Let $f \in Mod(S_g)$, define mapping torus $M_f= \dfrac{S_g \times [0,1]}{(x,0) \sim(\phi(x),1)}$, where $[\phi]=f$, more precisely $\phi$ represenatative for $f$ and $\phi \in Homeo^+(S_g)$.

If $f$ is pseudo-Anosov, then $M_f$ is a closed hyperbolic three-manifold.
My question is the following I want to look at simple closed geodesic in $M_f$. Are they infinitely many in $M_f$?

My attempt is the following.

I am using the fact For any pseudo-Anosov homeomorphism $\phi$ of a compact
surface $S$, the periodic points of $\phi$ are dense in $S$. Let $P_{\phi}$ be the set of all periodic points for $\phi$. Take $x \in P_{\phi}$ with period $n$ say then $x$ is fixed point of the pseudo-anosov map $\phi^n$, now consider the arc $x$ in $S_g \times \{0\}$ to $S_g \times \{1\}$, this is an embedded arc in $S_g \times [0,1]$ therefore in the mapping torus $M_{\phi^n}$ it will from a simple closed loop, here is also I have a question is this simple closed loop isotopic to a simple closed geodesic in $M_{\phi^n}$?....This is how I have thought to produce simple closed geodesics in $M_f$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your argument does not prove anything since every simple loop in a 3-manifold is homotopic to a non-simple one.

Comment: Yes, true, my question is basically, the special loop constructed above, in this loop class(up to free homotopy), contains a unique geodesic representative, is it simple?

Comment: I think the answer will be that sometimes yes, sometimes not.

Comment: Can you give some examples or references when it is true and when it is not?

Comment: For instance, there are hyperbolic 3-manifolds where every closed geodesic is simple (or an iterate of a simple geodesic).

Comment: Can you give some references or examples?  Is this hyperbolic that 3-manifolds are closed? Are these manifolds homeomorphic to mapping torus (like I discussed above) via some pseudo-anosov map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145703/discussion-between-t-ghosh-and-moishe-kohan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 9.7.2 in

*Maclachlan, Colin; Reid, Alan W.*, [**The arithmetic of hyperbolic 3-manifolds**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/320387), Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 219. New York, NY: Springer. xiii, 463 p. (2003). [ZBL1025.57001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1025.57001).

**Theorem.** There are infinitely many commensurability classes of (arithmetic) compact hyperbolic 3-manifolds where all closed geodesics are simple.

To connect to your question: It is now known (I. Agol, et al) that all finite volume hyperbolic 3-manifolds are virtually fibered over the circle. Therefore, WLOG, one can assume that manifolds in the above theorem are fibered over the circle.